# AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NavigationViewlet'

Tags: plone

here is my traceback from a Plone 4.2.1 installation (on SuSE Linux):

```
Traceback (innermost last):

Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 126, in publish
Module ZPublisher.mapply, line 77, in mapply
Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 46, in call_object
Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 620, in manage_importObject
Module OFS.ObjectManager, line 638, in _importObjectFromFile
Module ZODB.ExportImport, line 92, in importFile
Module transaction._transaction, line 260, in savepoint
Module transaction._transaction, line 257, in savepoint
Module transaction._transaction, line 690, in __init__
Module ZODB.Connection, line 1123, in savepoint
Module ZODB.Connection, line 587, in _commit
Module ZODB.ExportImport, line 176, in _importDuringCommit

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'NavigationViewlet'
```

The strange thing, that I do not understand is, why only one Plone Site shows this error during import into an instance newer than Plone 4.1.5?

The Plone site has only the following additional plugins/products installed (as others too, but they all work fine):

- LinguaPlone
- PloneFormGen
- Products.ZSyncer
- collective.quickupload

So, where is my mistake/error?

Thanx for any help, because the site is too big now to "rebuild" it in a new Plone instance from scratch :-(

Answer (score 2):

The `plone.app.layout.viewlets.links.NavigationViewlet` was removed in `plone.app.layout` version 2.2 (see [this entry into the HTML5 PLIP](https://dev.plone.org/ticket/11300#comment:39) and [this commit](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.layout/commit/3aa2c5448646cd1b7db5ef8f5a06a5fae64b3795)).

ZEXP imports into different version stacks are generally fraught with problems, exactly because of changing persistent object locations. You'll have to import to an earlier version of the software stack, then follow the regular [Plone upgrade path](http://plone.org/documentation/manual/upgrade-guide) to bring yourself up to a more recent version of Plone.

The upgrade scripts take care of removing references to removed viewlets like these, for example.